# For loop not performing as it should C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, i am a learner in C# and i am creating a simple app that lets you input a code which is a string, then you enter another string and if(string1 == string2) it outputs "Access granted", if not it says "Wrong code, try again" and goes back to start. Now i want to create a variable NumberOfTries, which if(NumberOfTries == 0) outputs "Safe locked" and exits the program. The problem is it only goes 2 times through the loop, i don't know why, no matter what value i give it. Here is the code:

```
int NumberOfTries = 3; //Even when = 10, it only goes 2 times
Console.WriteLine("Safe code: ");          
string input= Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Safe code is: " +input);

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTries; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Input code: ");
    string code= Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == code)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Access granted!");
         break;
      }
      else
      {                   
         Console.WriteLine("Wrong code, try again!");
         NumberOfTries--;           
      }                
   }

    if (NumberOfTries == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Safe locked!");

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Seems like a homework problem... But why are you decrementing the *number of tries* when the code is wrong? Perhaps rename NumberOfTries to MaxNumberOfTries and see whether that helps you understand the cause...

Comment: The code you posted will execute the loop body 5 times when the `NumberOfTries` variable is initialized to 10, not 2 times as you claim. Please post an actual [mcve] that will reproduce the behavior you claim.

Comment: See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and of course https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio and similar documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were getting 2 passes with a NumberOfTries set to 10 then you weren't re-compiling your code before executing it again.  Running that code would with a NumberOfTries set to 10 would give you 5 attempts. This is because you are decrementing the condition of the `for` loop with each failed attempt.

Entry check: i=0, NumberOfTries = 10

2nd check: i = 1, NumberOfTries = 9

3rd check: i = 2, NumberOfTries = 8

4th check: i = 3, NumberOfTries = 7

5th check: i = 4, NumberOfTries = 6

6th check: i = 5, NumberOfTries = 5 -> Bail

To get the desired behavior, you should distinguish between the maximum attempt count and the number of attempts:

```
int maxTries = 3;
int numberOfTries = 0;
 
Console.WriteLine("Safe code: ");          
string input= Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Safe code is: " +input);

for (int i = 0; i < maxTries; i++)
{
    numberOfTries++;
    Console.WriteLine("Input code: ");
    string code= Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access granted!");
        break;
    }
    else if (numberOfTries < maxTries)
    {                   
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong code, try again!");
    }                
}

if (numberOfTries >= maxTries)
    Console.WriteLine("Safe locked!");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Rather than trying to decrement a try count, we allow the loop to iterate over the # of allowed tries (maxTries) and record the attempt, incrementing a try counter (numberOfTries). When the user gets it wrong we just check that they aren't on their last try before displaying "Try Again", and on exiting the loop we check if they used all of their tries before locking.

You can modify conditions on C# `for` loops but you need to be careful when doing it to avoid unexpected side effects.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks, it works now :D

Answer (score 0):

When = 10, it will go 5 times. Since you have set condition `i < NumberOfTries` in the for statement, there is no need to execute `NumberOfTries--;` in `else`.

You can judge the number of times the for has looped according to the value of i, and output "Safe locked!" when the opportunity runs out.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTries; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input code: ");
    string code = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access granted!");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        if (i == NumberOfTries - 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Safe locked!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong code, try again!");
        }
    }
}
```